# Need more information on Drools -version 7.X.X compatibility with java11

Tags: java, drools, compatibility, java-11

Does anyone know that is there any compatibility issues with `drools 7.5.0.Final` and above + for `java 11`?

Also does the latest drools version documentation or any link provides any information about drools compatibility with `java 11.`  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official confirmation Drools works on Java 11. [Here is the link from forum.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/mGCIVrNIfOE)

You can always check Droops Usage Forum , where I found the questions on
compatibility issues.

Some reports suggest that it works without compatibility issues on `Drolls 7.22.0.Final`.